# Inserting values into a SQL Server database using ado.net via C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, executenonquery

I have created a simple program to insert values into the table `[regist]`, but I keep getting the error

> *Incorrect syntax near ')'*

on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2 ; User ID=sa;Password=sqlpass;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.regist (" + " FirstName, Lastname, Username, Password, Age, Gender,Contact, " + ") VALUES (" + " @textBox1.Text, @textBox2.Text, @textBox3.Text, @textBox4.Text, @comboBox1.Text,@comboBox2.Text,@textBox7.Text" + ")", cn);

      cn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cn.Close();
}
```

I am new to this and I am really confused.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to name the parameters like that?

Answer (score 58):

As I said in comments - you should **always** use parameters in your query - **NEVER EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements yourself.

Also: I would recommend to separate the click event handler from the actual code to insert the data.

So I would rewrite your code to be something like

In your web page's code-behind file (`yourpage.aspx.cs`)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string connectionString = "Data Source=DELL-PC;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2 ; User ID=sa;Password=sqlpass;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

      InsertData(connectionString,
                 textBox1.Text.Trim(),  -- first name
                 textBox2.Text.Trim(),  -- last name
                 textBox3.Text.Trim(),  -- user name
                 textBox4.Text.Trim(),  -- password
                 Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text),  -- age
                 comboBox2.Text.Trim(), -- gender
                 textBox7.Text.Trim() );  -- contact
}
```

In some other code (e.g. a `databaselayer.cs`):

```
private void InsertData(string connectionString, string firstName, string lastname, string username, string password
                        int Age, string gender, string contact)
{
    // define INSERT query with parameters
    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.regist (FirstName, Lastname, Username, Password, Age, Gender,Contact) " + 
                   "VALUES (@FirstName, @Lastname, @Username, @Password, @Age, @Gender, @Contact) ";

    // create connection and command
    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        // define parameters and their values
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = firstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = lastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = userName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = age;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = gender;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = contact;

        // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Code like this:

- is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks
- performs much better on SQL Server (since the query is parsed once into an execution plan, then cached and reused later on)
- separates the event handler (code-behind file) from your actual database code (putting things where they belong - helping to avoid "overweight" code-behinds with tons of spaghetti code, doing everything from handling UI events to database access - **NOT** a good design!)

Comment: Great answer, +1. I have been trying to find some official documentation on how to do this, but the samples I have found on MSDN are not very detailed (like this answer). Do you have any good source/reference for the answer you provided above? Or is it taken directly from the top of your mind? ;)

Answer (score 7):

Remove the comma

```
... Gender,Contact, " + ") VALUES ...
                  ^-----------------here
```

Comment: Sure this is the problem, but parameters are used and not defined. Also, `@textBox1.Text` would not be a valid SQL parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Following Code will work for "**Inserting values into a SQL Server database using ado.net via C#**"

```
// Your Connection string
string connectionString = "Data Source=DELL-PC;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2 ; User ID=sa;Password=sqlpass;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

// Collecting Values
string firstName="Name",
    lastName="LastName",
    userName="UserName",
    password="123",
    gender="Male",
    contact="Contact";
int age=26; 

// Query to be executed
string query = "Insert Into dbo.regist (FirstName, Lastname, Username, Password, Age, Gender,Contact) " + 
                   "VALUES (@FN, @LN, @UN, @Pass, @Age, @Gender, @Contact) ";

    // instance connection and command
    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        // add parameters and their values
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FN", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = firstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LN", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = lastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UN", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = userName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = age;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = gender;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = contact;

        // open connection, execute command and close connection
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should remove last comma and as nrodic said your command is not correct.

you should change it like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.regist (" + " FirstName, Lastname, Username, Password, Age, Gender,Contact " + ") VALUES (" + " textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, comboBox1.Text,comboBox2.Text,textBox7.Text" + ")", cn);
```

Comment: while it works this wont protect against SQL injection

Comment: No need to demote if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "data source=CHANCHAL\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AssetManager;user id=GIPL-PC\GIPL;password=";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from detail1", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(ad);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("detail1");
    ad.Fill(ds, "detail1");
    DataRow row = ds.Tables["detail1"].NewRow();
    row["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
    row["address"] =textBox2.Text;
    ds.Tables["detail1"].Rows.Add(row);
    ad.Update(ds, "detail1");
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("insert secussfully"); 
}
```