# incorrect syntax near '' unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I've created a Web Form using C# within Visual Web Dev 2010 Express and it contains text boxes / labels (based on check boxes) but when I run the code to fails on running the SQL command. I have gotten the code to work before using only 3 text boxes but doesn't seem to work when I expand the code.

Things I have tried:

When googling someone said something about quotation marks being an issue (and the error reflects that) but if I remove all the quotations from the SQL command it fails but my thoughts were it always had to be `'"+datahere+"'` is that true?

I will also quote all of my code behind for the web form in question below the error. The error looks like this when I run a 'debug':

> Incorrect syntax near 't'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 't'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Source Error:

```
Line 40:             }
Line 41:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sicknesstest values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtgrade.Text+"','"+txtdepot.Text+"','"+txtillness.Text+"','"+txtabsence.Text+"','"+txtcontactby.Text+"','"+txtupdate.Text+"','"+txtdetails.Text+"','"+txtresumedate.Text+"','"+txtdetail.Text+"','"+txtmedonreturn.Text+"','"+txtreporter.Text+"','"+txtdateofcontact.Text+"','"+txtresumeddate.Text+"')", con);
Line 42:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 43:             con.Close();
Line 44:             Label1.Visible = true;
```

Source File: C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SicknessDBNewSite\SicknessDBNewSite\WebForm2.aspx.cs    Line: 42

Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 't'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1791910
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5347106
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +869
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +413
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
   SicknessDBNewSite.WebForm2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SicknessDBNewSite\SicknessDBNewSite\WebForm2.aspx.cs:42
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9653178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

---

Code behind:
webform2.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="SicknessDBNewSite.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 72%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 443px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .style4
        {
            width: 443px;
            height: 65px;
        }
        .style5
        {
            height: 65px;
        }
        .style6
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1 class="style3">
            Test Form Submission
        </h1>
        <table class="style1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Grade</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtgrade" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Depot</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdepot" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Nature of Illness?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtillness" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Appointment made to see doctor (Yes or No)?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioAppointmentYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioAppointmentNo" runat="server" Text="No" />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelAppointment" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Medication Taken (Yes or No)?</td>
                <td class="style6">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioMedicationYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioMedicationNo" runat="server" Text="No" />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelMedication" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Expected length of absence?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtabsence" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    If not contacted by staff member, who contacted on their behalf?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontactby" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Likely resumption date?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtresumedate" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Contact telephone number</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontactnum" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Latest update date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdate" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    Details</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdetails" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Resumption Date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtresumeddate" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Detail</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdetail" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Is the person still on medication at the time of resumption?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmedonreturn" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Controller / Planner&#39;s name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtreporter" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Date of contact</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofcontact" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Date and time of next shift</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdatetimeshift" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="100px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <a href="http://INTRANET/webform1.aspx">
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Visible="False" /></asp:Label>
     </a>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringTestFormSubmission %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [sicknesstest]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webform2.aspx.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SicknessDBNewSite
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringTestFormSubmission"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (RadioAppointmentYes.Checked)
            {
                LabelAppointment.Text = "Yes";
            }
            else if (RadioAppointmentNo.Checked)
            {
                LabelAppointment.Text = "No";
            }

            if (RadioMedicationYes.Checked)
            {
                LabelAppointment.Text = "Yes";
            }
            else if (RadioMedicationNo.Checked)
            {
                LabelAppointment.Text = "No";
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sicknesstest values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtgrade.Text+"','"+txtdepot.Text+"','"+txtillness.Text+"','"+LabelAppointment.Text+"','"+LabelMedication.Text+"','"+txtabsence.Text+"','"+txtcontactby.Text+"','"+txtupdate.Text+"','"+txtdetails.Text+"','"+txtresumedate.Text+"','"+txtdetail.Text+"','"+txtmedonreturn.Text+"','"+txtreporter.Text+"','"+txtdateofcontact.Text+"','"+txtresumeddate.Text+"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Your Data has been stored successfully! Click here to view";
            txtname.Text = "";
            txtgrade.Text = "";
            txtdepot.Text = "";
            txtillness.Text = "";
            txtabsence.Text = "";
            txtcontactby.Text = "";
            txtupdate.Text = "";
            txtdetails.Text = "";
            txtresumedate.Text = "";
            txtdetail.Text = "";
            txtmedonreturn.Text = "";
            txtreporter.Text = "";
            txtdateofcontact.Text = "";
            txtresumeddate.Text = "";
        }
    }

}
```

--
Datesource:

WebConfig :

The database runs locally on my machine as a 'test bay' and works find as far as I can see.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringTestFormSubmission" connectionString="Data Source=G00069-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SicknessDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=REMOVED;Password=REMOVED"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: It is a SQL error. Please delete all the unrelated code from the question.

Comment: Look up *Prepared Statements* It will make it so much easier for you and the error will probably go away if you change your code accordingly.

Comment: Found the issue, it seems to be related to having " wasn't " within my text box causing the SQL to terminate (SQL injection?) and removing it fixed the issue, but getting another error now :( 

`String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: I suggest you convert your script into Stored Procedure.

Comment: You need to escape all of your inputs so that single quotes are doubled. You also need to not do it this way - note all the other comments and answers about SQL injection.

Comment: Jamie, that _other_ issue is a good enough reason for _another_ question, that's the way SO works. Suggest you finish up on this one (upvote/accept however you feel most helped) then ask it as a new question. If you change the very nature of a question, it renders all answers useless.

Comment: @RhysJones Your second sentence is correct. Your first sentence is oh-so wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

92.7% <sup>(a)</sup> of all SQL execution problems become evident if you output the string before you try to execute it.

Chances are you have a stray quote somewhere in your input fields, not necessarily malicious - it could be caused by such things as `oh no, we won't go` or `code doesn't work` or `contact Mr O'Rourke`.

That means doing something like:

```
string strcmd = "insert into ...";
// Examine/output strcmd here.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcmd);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Then, once you've got it working, look up the two terms "SQL injection attack" and "SQL prepared statements". At some point, you'll want to start using the latter to prevent the former.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Figure pulled out of thin air, *actual* value may vary :-)

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion would be to use parameter in query instead of concatenation. An example of using parameter in sql query is as follows:

```
IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM M_ITEM_SERIAL WHERE ITSR_PLANT_ID = @plantId";

IDbDataParameter plantIdParam = command.CreateParameter();
plantIdParam.ParameterName = "@plantId";
plantIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
plantIdParam.Value = plantId;
command.Parameters.Add(plantIdParam);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will give it a go :), any suggestions on websites or vids to try and learn this sort of stuff? As currently learning by 'doing' so to speak.

Comment: I think MSDN is a great place to start with. But there are plenty of videos in youtube about ADO.net in general.

Comment: @JamieB well, where did you learn about `SqlCommand`? It is a pretty good bet that it also mentioned parameterization... if not: (shudder)

Comment: @MarcGravell it was via Youtube because I couldn't get my head around all the code people were putting up, reverse engineered a youtube tutorial and nothing was said about SQL injections or any other form of doing it...

However the work I'm doing for my work project is intranet only, but will want to cover all bases and its a good habit to get into :)

Comment: @JamieB I think that demonstrates that youtube is not a recommended training channel...

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed, but its what I have to hand at the time :).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild your statement. And in c# i never would concat strings like that, please use `String.Format` for that. In general you even should not pass parameter this way to the database, because of SQL-injection. Try to use `SqlParameter`.

I think your problem occures because of wrong values in some Text-Box, this can't happen when you are using `SqlParameter`.

You should read this SO-Answer: [Inserting values into a SQL Server database using ado.net via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573824/2630261)