# Trying to read data from sql database and show on textboxes - Visual C# (syntax error)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**edit: I'm aware of SQL Injection.**

First of all, I know my coding methods are terrible but thats what I can for now, extremely beginner on c#.

I'm trying to read data from SQL server and show them on Textboxes. 
User going to write (and choose from cmbbox) some data on;

> cmbIl.Text, cmbIlce.Text, cmbMahalle.Text, txtAda.Text, txtPafta.Text

and press the button for search.

If that data correspond to the values in sql database (true), some other data will be taken and shown at

> txtTapuKodu.Text, txtPafta.Text, txtTapuAlani.Text, txtNitelik.Text,
>   rtxtImarDurumu.Text

But the code below gives that error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

```
 private void btnSorgula_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string source = @"Data Source=YAGIZ-PC;Initial Catalog=imar_sorgu;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
            con.Open();

            string sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE il = '" + cmbIl.Text + "', ilce = '" + cmbIlce.Text + "', mahalle = '" + cmbMahalle.Text + "', ada = '" + txtAda.Text + "', parsel = '" + txtParsel.Text + "'";

            /* string sqlSelectQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE ilce ='" + cmbIlce.Text + "'";
            string sqlSelectQuery3 = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE mahalle ='" + cmbMahalle.Text + "'";
            string sqlSelectQuery4 = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE ada = " + txtAda.Text;
            string sqlSelectQuery5 = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE parsel = " + txtParsel.Text; */

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                txtTapuKodu.Text = (dr["tapu_kodu"].ToString());
                txtPafta.Text = (dr["pafta"].ToString());
                txtTapuAlani.Text = (dr["tapu_alani"].ToString());
                txtNitelik.Text = (dr["nitelik"].ToString());
                rtxtImarDurumu.Text = (dr["imar_durumu"].ToString());

                MessageBox.Show("İstek başarıyla okundu.");

            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Okuma başarısız.");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Read about sql injection before allowing users to place their strings into your sql

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573380/10293483), take a look at this solution. It's better not to concatenate your sql query. Just use parameters and you won't get these errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that your where clause contains commas between the predicates.  use AND instead.

change:

```
    string sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE il = '" + cmbIl.Text + "', ilce = '" + cmbIlce.Text + "', mahalle = '" + cmbMahalle.Text + "', ada = '" + txtAda.Text + "', parsel = '" + txtParsel.Text + "'";
```

to:

```
    string sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablo_arsa WHERE il = '" + cmbIl.Text + "' AND ilce = '" + cmbIlce.Text + "' AND mahalle = '" + cmbMahalle.Text + "' AND ada = '" + txtAda.Text + "' AND parsel = '" + txtParsel.Text + "'";
```

However, PLEASE read about SQL INJECTION.  It is a very bad security issue and this is a perfect example.

Comment: Thank you for help and advice. It worked. I appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure of the reason for the down vote.  I can guess.  True that I did not provide a parameterized query example.  Also, did not mention that 'select *' should be avoided in code.  However, both of those issues are out of the scope of the question.  And, I did strongly suggest studying up on sql injection.