# Insert data in a table with foreign keys from c#

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys

I am making a a WindowsFormsApp and I have to get by a ComboBox, *idCategory* that is the primary key of Table Category. The thing is this is a foreign key in Table Contract and I don't know how to make the query in C# since it looks is a different way.

```
cmdContract.CommandText = "Insert into Contract(idCategory, ContractNumber) VALUES" +
"((Select idCategory from  Category where idCategory=" + idCategory + "),@ContractNumber");
```

I have another table that doesn't have foreign keys and works good, but with this one, Contract, it doesn't insert anything

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) | [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Answer (score 0):

If you know CategoryId and you are sure that a record with this CategoryId exists in DB, your query has to look like this: `Insert into Contract(idCategory, ContractNumber) VALUES (@idCategory, @ContractNumber)` (without inner `select` statement).

And one more advice: don't concatenate string for building a query, use the command with parameters ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573380/inserting-values-into-a-sql-server-database-using-ado-net-via-c-sharp))